# EJB 3.1 in war package in WEB-INF/classes - javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1, java-ee-6

I think, I misunderstood rules of packaging ejb beans in war package.

**Goal:** I want to use ejb beans in war package.

**Scenario:** I have some bean in my war:

```
@Stateless
public class RegistrationServiceBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Utopia")
    EntityManager em;

    public RegistrationServiceBean() {}

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/15")
    public void baseRegistration() {
        System.out.println("call from ejb!!");
    }

    public void saveTempPartner(OasysPartnerTempEntity part) {
        em.persist(part);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

It successfully deploying to glassfish server (ogs 3.0.1) :

> [#|2010-07-02T16:53:59.728+0300|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Portable
>   JNDI names for EJB
>   RegistrationServiceBean :
>   [java:global/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBean!ua.co.oasys.hydra.beans.RegistrationServiceBean,
>   java:global/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBean]|#]

But when the scheduler is starting I get :

> [#|2010-07-02T16:54:20.004+0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|A
>   system exception occurred during an
>   invocation on EJB
>   RegistrationServiceBean method public
>   void
>   ua.co.oasys.hydra.beans.RegistrationServiceBean.baseRegistration()
>   javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:448)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2467)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1860)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3962)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1667)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:98)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2485)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:720)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:200)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:443)
>    ... 12 more Caused by:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:528)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:90)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:718)
>    ... 14 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
>    at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:1171)
>    at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:132)
>    at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:145)
>    at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:122)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1616)
>    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:469)
>    ... 16 more |#]

All application packaged in in ear with war inside, it works good if I am deploying ejb in ejb-jar, but is not what I want.

After I removed weld dependency, I got exception during deployment:

> com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CommandException:
>   remote failure: Exception while
>   loading the app :
>   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException:
>   by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ua/co/oasys/hydra/beans/RegistrationServiceBean

It is similar to  [glassfish bug](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11536), but I am not sure .

---

updates:
 web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>CO UA Partners</display-name>
    <description>CO UA Partners Site</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!--Prime Faces-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>sam</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <!--Prime Faces end-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Manager Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/partner/manager/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/partner/manager/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/partner/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/partner/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>manager</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/partner/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/partner/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/partner/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/partner/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!--roots-->


    <security-role>
        <role-name>rmanager</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>radmin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>bookkeper</role-name>
    </security-role>


    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>oasysRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>



</web-app>
```

NoClassDefFoundError exception :

> [#|2010-07-04T16:16:26.401+0300|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception
>   while loading the app
>   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException:
>   by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ua/co/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBea
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ua/co/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBea
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:344)
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:314)
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.createProxyClass(Proxies.java:187)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.createProxyClass(Proxies.java:168)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.initProxyClass(SessionBean.java:221)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.initialize(SessionBean.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:110)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:151)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:377)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:165)
>     ... 30 more Caused by:
>   javassist.CannotCompileException: by
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ua/co/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBea
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:169)
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:339)
>     ... 40 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ua/co/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBea
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor196.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:181)
>     at
>   javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:163)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ua.co.oasys.hydra.RegistrationServiceBea
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:713)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:626)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>     ... 49 more |#]

---

Update 2:

If remove/rename beans.xml file ejbs deployed successfully.

---

Update 3:

oasys.ear

> jar xfv
>   ~/Sites/workspace/Intellij_IDEA_9/Oasys/Oasys-ear/target/oasys.ear
>   created: META-INF/  inflated:
>   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF   created: lib/ 
>   inflated: fenix.jar  inflated:
>   hydra.war  inflated:
>   javax.inject-1.jar  inflated:
>   jboss-interceptor-api-1.1-CR1.jar 
>   inflated: jsr250-api-1.0.jar 
>   inflated: lib/cdi-api-1.0-CR4.jar 
>   inflated:
>   lib/eclipselink-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
>   inflated:
>   lib/javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar 
>   inflated: lib/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar 
>   inflated: lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.0.jar 
>   inflated: lib/utopia.jar  inflated:
>   lib/weld-logger-1.0.0-CR2.jar 
>   inflated: META-INF/application.xml
>   created: META-INF/maven/   created:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/   created:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/oasys-ear/ 
>   inflated:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/oasys-ear/pom.xml
>   inflated:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/oasys-ear/pom.properties

hydra.war

> jar xfv
>   ~/Sites/workspace/Intellij_IDEA_9/Oasys/Hydra/target/hydra.war
>   created: META-INF/  inflated:
>   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF   created:
>   partner/   created: partner/admin/
>   created: partner/manager/   created:
>   resources/   created: resources/css/
>   created: resources/css/sam/   created:
>   resources/css/sam/images/   created:
>   resources/layout/   created:
>   resources/security/   created: root/
>   created: root/admin/   created:
>   root/bookkeeper/   created:
>   root/manager/   created: WEB-INF/
>   created: WEB-INF/classes/   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/common/   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ 
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/registration/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/
>   created:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/
>   created: WEB-INF/lib/  inflated:
>   html5.html  inflated: index.xhtml 
>   inflated: login.xhtml  inflated:
>   loginError.xhtml  inflated:
>   partner/admin/admin.xhtml  inflated:
>   partner/manager/manager.xhtml 
>   inflated: partner/partner.xhtml 
>   inflated: register.xhtml  inflated:
>   resources/css/cssLayout.css  inflated:
>   resources/css/default.css  inflated:
>   resources/css/master.css  inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/sprite.png 
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png  inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
>   inflated:
>   resources/css/sam/images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
>   inflated: resources/css/sam/skin.css 
>   inflated:
>   resources/layout/doublevontent.xhtml 
>   inflated:
>   resources/layout/header.xhtml 
>   inflated:
>   resources/layout/masterLayout.xhtml 
>   inflated:
>   resources/prime-themes/vader/skin.css 
>   inflated:
>   resources/security/loginPanel.xhtml 
>   inflated: root/admin/radmin.xhtml 
>   inflated:
>   root/bookkeeper/rbookkeeper.xhtml 
>   inflated: root/manager/rmanager.xhtml 
>   inflated: WEB-INF/beans.xml  inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/common/SkinBean.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/messages.properties
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/messages_en_US.properties
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/messages_ru_RU.properties
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/messages_uk_UA.properties
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/Messenger.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/registration/TempReg.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/LogOutActionListener.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/LogoutServlet.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/RulesBean.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/SecurityBacking.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/UserBean.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/security/UserManager.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/Messages.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/Utf8ResourceBundle$1.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/Utf8ResourceBundle$Utf8PropertyResourceBundle.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/mb/ua/co/oasys/hydra/i18n/Utf8ResourceBundle.class
>   inflated:
>   WEB-INF/classes/ua/co/oasys/hydra/RegistrationServiceBea.class
>   inflated: WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
>
> inflated:
>   WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-2.1.RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   inflated: WEB-INF/sun-web.xml 
>   inflated: WEB-INF/web.xml   created:
>   META-INF/maven/   created:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/   created:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/hydra/ 
>   inflated:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/hydra/pom.xml
>   inflated:
>   META-INF/maven/ua.co.oasys/hydra/pom.properties

---

- Q1: is it passable to use ejb beans packaged in war (specification sad that is true)?
- Q2: should I describe some configuration by ejb-jar.xml ?
- Q3: what could be a cause of a problem?

Answer (score 1):

> It is similar to glassfish bug, but I am not sure .

Hard to say, especially since you didn't provide the stacktrace for the `NoClassDefFoundError`, but the scenario seems different anyway.

> Q1: is it passable to use ejb beans packaged in war (specification sad that is true)?

Definitely. You can either put EJB classes in `WEB-INF/classes` or package them as EJB-JAR and put them in `WEB-INF/lib`. I have several demo applications doing this.

> Q2: should I describe some configuration by ejb-jar.xml ?

No, nothing forces you to do so.

> Q3: what could be a cause of a problem?

The problem is that I couldn't reproduce the problem... I've deployed your EJB in a webapp with `[ejb, jpa, web, webservices, weld]` engines enabled (I just modified it to insert an Entity of mine in the scheduled method) and it just works. Tested with an up-to-date version of GlassFish 3.0.1. So I suspect a mistake or configuration problem on your side.

Just in case, can you provide the output of `jar xfv yourapp.war` (and also show your `web.xml`)?

Comment: I crate addition question with project link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175458/cdi-with-ejb-3-1-weld-logger-on-glassfish-v3-0-1

Answer (score 0):

EJBs packaged in a WAR are using the web / lite profile of EE6. As far as I know, timers and some other features are not supported in this profile. <del>So if you want to use timers you would have to package your ejbs in the traditional ejbjar + war + ear way.</del>

I could not find a reference for the web profile, this is the closest to a comparison: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321142/Part-Three-New-Features-in-EJB-31

**Edit:** I stand corrected, war packaging is actually described in jsr 318, EJB 3.1. Since I could not find any restrictions on available features in that section of the spec, timers should also work in an ejb packaged in a war.

Comment: This is **incorrect**. When packaged in a WAR (vs EAR), only the class loading of EJBs is different (see the section **20.4 Enterprise Beans Packaged in a .war** of the specification for full details). But using a WAR packaging and using a web profile implementation are just two **unrelated**  things. I'm using a WAR packaging with the "full" implementation and timers just work.