# CDI not working in ear deployed to glassfish v3.0.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, ejb-3.1, java-ee-6

I have some problem with using weld logger injection.

**Scenario:** I have ear with ejb-jar inside.

This is my ejb bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PartnersService {
    @Inject
    Logger log;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Utopia")
    EntityManager em;

    public PartnersService() {
    }

    public OasysPartnerEntity getPartner(long id){
        return em.find(OasysPartnerEntity.class, id);
    }

    @Schedule( hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/15")
    public void print1Partner(){
        System.out.println("This is test");
        log.info("This is partner`s email under id 1 = ");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveTempPartnerTemp(OasysPartnerTempEntity part){
        em.persist(part);
    }

}
```

when print1Partner called I got exception:

> |2010-07-02T19:25:35.003+0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=48;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|A
>   system exception occurred during an
>   invocation on EJB PartnersService
>   method public void
>   ua.co.oasys.fenix.persistence.PartnersService.print1Partner()
>   javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:448)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2467)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1860)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3962)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1667)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:98)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2485)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:720)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:200)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:443)
>     ... 12 more Caused by:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not
>   create stateless EJB  at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:528)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:718)
>     ... 14 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:1171)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:145)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1616)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:469)
>     ... 16 more |#]

Using: ejb 3.1, glassfish 3.0.1

Some of maven dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- SL4J API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Injectable Weld-Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
            <!--CDI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.0-CR4</version>
        </dependency>
```

ear pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
....
<!--weld-->
        <!-- SL4J API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Injectable Weld-Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>

            <version>1.0-CR4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
<build>
...
<configuration>
                    <modules>
...
                       <!--weld-->
                        <!-- SL4J API -->
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>

                        <!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>

                        <!-- Injectable Weld-Logger -->
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                            <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>

                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

bean.xml in META-INF/

Same configuration working with war in ear without ejb (in war, but if I use ejb in war and weld - same exception)

Q1: what is wrong?

Q2: what is the rules of using weld & ejb 3.1 ?

Comment: Is your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166596/ejb-3-1-in-war-package-in-web-inf-classes-javax-ejb-createexception-could-not) solved? If it isn't, I'd try to solve it first before to introduce more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The Weld Logger and SFLF4J artifacts are **NOT** provided, if you want to use them, you need to add them to your application:

```
<!-- SL4J API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Injectable Weld-Logger -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Foo {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public void bar() {
        logger.info("Look ma, I'm using an injected Logger!");
    }
}
```

I'm using the weld-logger myself (with logback as binding) and tested your code under GlassFish 3.0.1, it just works.

Comment: I include them in ear /lib directory.
see update [ear pom.xml]

Comment: could you check if it works if Foo become @Steateless and packaged in war inside ear package ?
Thanks

Comment: I crate addition question with project link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175458/cdi-with-ejb-3-1-weld-logger-on-glassfish-v3-0-1