# Why is Glassfish 3.1.1 unable to create my Stateless Session Bean?

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi, ejb-3.1

Glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12)
Application deployed as a WAR using JAX-RS, EJB3, JPA

There are no deployment errors in the logs.  This is a very clean glassfish 3.1.1 install, with only this application deployed. *This application works in Glassfish 3.0.1*  I am getting the following exception when web service method is invoked.

EJB5070: Exception creating stateless session bean : [VehicleManagementService]|#]

**Here is some info from the logs during deployment regarding the creation of the EJBs:**

```
[#|2011-08-26T11:03:26.928-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Portable JNDI names for EJB VehicleAliases : [java:global/vehicle/VehicleAliases!com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleAliases, java:global/vehicle/VehicleAliases]|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:26.937-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Portable JNDI names for EJB VehicleManagementService : [java:global/vehicle/VehicleManagementService!com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.VehicleManagementService, java:global/vehicle/VehicleManagementService]|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.002-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Portable JNDI names for EJB VehicleManagementBean : [java:global/vehicle/VehicleManagementBean!com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleManagementBean, java:global/vehicle/VehicleManagementBean!com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleManagement]|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.003-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB VehicleManagementBean : [com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleManagement, com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleManagement#com.realcomp.vehicle.ejb.VehicleManagement]|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.218-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.602-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) for context '/vehicle'|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.660-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:27.771-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
/WEB-INF/lib
/WEB-INF/classes|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:28.072-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Root resource classes found:
class com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.VehicleManagementService|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:28.073-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
  class com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.NoResultMapper
  class com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.EntityNotFoundMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.NonUniqueResultMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:28.078-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|CDI support is enabled|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:28.079-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'|#]

[#|2011-08-26T11:03:28.172-0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBComponentProviderFactory|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Binding the EJB class com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.VehicleManagementService to EJBManagedComponentProvider|#]
```

**Here is some of the VehicleManagementService:**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/")
@DeclareRoles({"production"})
public class VehicleManagementService implements Serializable{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VehicleManagementService.class.getName());

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @EJB
    private VehicleManagementBean vehicles;

    @EJB
    private VehicleAliases aliases;

    ...
```

**Here is full stack trace:**

```
[#|2011-08-26T11:03:33.537-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5070: Exception creating stateless session bean : [VehicleManagementService]|#]
[#|2011-08-26T11:03:33.538-0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB VehicleManagementService method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.VehicleManagementService.getVehicle(java.lang.String)
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:454)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2528)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at $Proxy307.getVehicle(Unknown Source)
at com.realcomp.vehicle.web.service.__EJB31_Generated__VehicleManagementService__Intf____Bean__.getVehicle(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:726)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
... 53 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:796)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:1209)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:144)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:169)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:146)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1636)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
... 57 more
```

**And here is getVehicle()**

```
@GET
@Path("vin/{vin}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RolesAllowed("production")
public Response getVehicle(@PathParam("vin") String vin) {

    Vehicle vehicle = vehicles.find(vin);
    Response response = null;
    if (vehicle == null)
        response = Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    else
        response = Response.ok(vehicle).build();

    return response;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the getVehicle method. Can you post it. Also, 3.1.1 is supposed to be the clustered version of 3.1, so it might be a bug. Have you searched jira?

Comment: Added getVehicle() code to original question

Comment: Spent some time in Glassfish JIRA and Weld JIRA, and didn't find any related issues.  I will try Glassfish 3.1 and see if there is a difference.

Comment: I need to correct my earlier comment. 3.1x is the clustered version of 3.0x. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We solved the problem by adding the beans.xml to the all bundled projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes fixed my problem.  Unfortunately, I have changed too many things trying to fix this to be able to point to any one item.

I repackaged the application from WAR to EAR.

I changed the configuration of jersey from using the com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer configuration in web.xml to a proper class that extends Application.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class VehicleService extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> retVal = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    retVal.add(VehicleResource.class);
    retVal.add(EntityNotFoundMapper.class);
    retVal.add(NoResultMapper.class);
    retVal.add(NonUniqueResultMapper.class);
    return retVal;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    singletons.add(new org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    return singletons;
}
```

---

Thanks to JamesBoyZ for the link to [EJB 3.1 in war package in WEB-INF/classes - javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166596/ejb-3-1-in-war-package-in-web-inf-classes-javax-ejb-createexception-could-not) that got me going in the right direction.

Comment: You can find a nice article on combining EJB with Restfull web services here: http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-to-combine-rest-and-ejb-31

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd line of the stack trace, I saw:

```
A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB VehicleManagementService getVehicle(java.lang.String)
```

It seems there is a problem with your getVehicle method?

Comment: Yes, that is the method being invoked that causes the exception.

Comment: Have you read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166596/ejb-3-1-in-war-package-in-web-inf-classes-javax-ejb-createexception-could-not)? This guy seems to have the similar issue to yours. The 1st stack trace is quite similar too

Comment: I agree that seems to be the root cause of the problem.  It could be that the CDI implementation (weld) is not initializing something, but more likely is some silly configuration problem on my end.  I'll go look at the Weld source and see if I can glean some info.

Comment: I had not seen that question.  I will package it up as an EAR and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that there's a(n empty) beans.xml in your bundled project.